# Why can't my video play?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, video, playback

This is getting pretty frustrating. I make a video and willing to play it in js [with no jquery]. And everytime, it fail. The console said `play is not defined`. Can you help me please

```
<video id='video'>
        <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv' type='video/ogg'>
        <embed src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.flv' type='x-shockwave-flash'>
    </video>
    <button onclick='play()' >Play/Pause</button>
```

.

```
window.onload = function() {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
} else {
    video.pause();
}
};
```

- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function to play or pause should be separate from the document loading:

```
window.playPause = function () {
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('video');
    if (myVideo.paused) {
        myVideo.play();
    } else {
        myVideo.pause();
    }
};
```

...then, hook that up to your button:

```
<button onclick='playPause()'>Play/Pause</button>
```

This works for me with the video you're using. If you want the video to autoplay when the document loads (which isn't really a good idea) you should indicate that in the tag rather than the JavaScript:

```
<video id='video' autoplay>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the play method on the button. For the onClick event instead of just calling play, call the video element's play method.

```
<button onclick="video.play();">Play/Pause</button>
```